# How to echo to console in Laravel and Artisan?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, console, migration

I was curious, I'm using Laravel and Artisan for my migrations. Is there a method to output information to the console? I can't seem to find any information on this. For example:

```
<?php

class Generate_Sample_Users{

    public function up(){

        //Echo to console here
        echo "Creating sample users...";

        $generator = new Sample_Data();
        $user_count = 30;
        $users = array();


        for($i=0; $i < $user_count; $i++){
            array_push($users, $generator->generate_user($i));
        }

        DB::table('users')->insert($users);
    }

    public function down(){
        DB::table('users')->delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a hint, migrations are for creating schemas wherea seeds are for seeding your database. What you're doing above looks like a seed to me.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Karl, I create the schema using a different migration, then I run this migration to populate sample data for my development environment only. Is this an incorrect way of doing it?

Comment: If you are using Laravel 4, its better to do this with seeds: http://four.laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding

Comment: Awesome thanks. I love Laravel, it's always a step ahead.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Don't know if you are using Laravel 3 or Laravel 4, and if its also possible in Laravel 3, but i found this in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/commands).

```php
$this->info('Creating sample users...');
```

**EDIT**

If you switch to [database seeds](http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/migrations#database-seeding) you can use this to display a message

```php
$this->command->info('Creating sample users...');
```

Comment: It's Laravel 4, I get a call to undefined method error. Should I be extending a class in my migration?

Comment: Thanks ;) Just out of curiosity, is there a way to do this in Laravel 3?

Comment: Seeds? Can't find anything about it in the docs. Echo in console? Same, can't find anything about it.

Comment: Neither of these work for me in Laravel 4.2 from a Migration.

Comment: Deprecated for >4.0 versions of Laravel (including 4.2). Please update your answer.

Comment: `$this->info()` is only available to commands, not migrations.

Answer (score 44):

This works for me

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

class MigrateData {

    public function up()
    {
        $output = new ConsoleOutput();

        for($i=0; $i<50000; $i++)
        {
             $output->writeln('Converting '.$i.' of 50000');
        }
     }
}
```

I have a migration which is converting a large table into a more efficient format and use this to get some progress while it works.

Comment: This works for me on Laravel 4.2; the accepted answer doesn't

Answer (score 10):

For database seeding in Laravel5, you can use

```
$this->command->info('My info');
$this->command->error('My error');
```

to print the output on command line.

`info` shows the message in green color where as `error` shows in red color which can be used for error messages.

Comment: Works nicely for me in Laravel 5.8, thanks! (note that you can use <comment> (yellow), <question> (lightblue bg) or <error> (red bg) instead of <info> for different color effects)

Answer (score 9):

Since the chosen answer doesn't seem to work since 4.2, I say just keep it simple:

```
public function up() {
     // Migration runs //
     echo 'Records processed' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: yeah! Just keep it simple! work with any Laravel version :D

Answer (score 5):

I like the color added by the Dumper (tested on Laravel 5.3).  I think looks a bit nicer than using the echo.  The issue I have with the echo out is that it's too easy to be missed, the Dumper it adds a bit of green which catches ones eye:

```
public function up() {
     // Migration runs //
     (new Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper)->dump("A bit more colorful text");
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, now is it?

Comment: Why is this not an answer to the question?  It outputs the text that you want onto the console during a migration.  The only difference to the one answer above is that it is in a different color (green).

Answer (score 5):

Talking about Laravel 5 (you can check the version you have with `php artisan --version`), the Migration base-class has no printing method.

A simple `echo` will do the work, However, if you want, you can extend it and add this functionality:

```
abstract class MyMigration extends Migration
{
    // colors for console echo
    protected const COLOR_RED = 'COLOR_RED';
    protected const COLOR_GREEN = 'COLOR_GREEN';
    protected const COLOR_YELLOW = 'COLOR_YELLOW';

    protected function logMessage($str, String $color = null)
    {
        switch ($color) {
            case self::COLOR_RED:
                $str = "\033[01;31m$str\033[0m";
                break;
            case self::COLOR_GREEN:
                $str = "\033[01;32m$str\033[0m";
                break;
            case self::COLOR_YELLOW:
                $str = "\033[01;33m$str\033[0m";
            break;

            echo $str . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

and then simply call it with your message:

```
$this->logMessage("Your message", self::COLOR_RED );
```

Answer (score 3):

'Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;' works for me on Laravel 5.2

Answer (score -2):

Just use print()

e.g.

```
$var = 'test';
print("\n$var");
```