# How to print messages on console in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, logging

How do laravel print out some string on console when running php artisan serve?
I tried `Log::info` but it isn't working.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I write to the console from a Laravel Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25148662/608639), [How to echo to console in Laravel and Artisan?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16733957/608639)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with

```
error_log('message here.');
```

[Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353767/print-something-in-php-built-in-web-server)

---

If You ant add LOG

```
Log::info('message');
```

If LOG with an array

```
Log::info(json_encode($array));
```

> Import `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;`

---

You can use [`dump()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-dump) as well. If you use this you have to use `dd()` or `die` after this.

---

**Apart from all this you can use `dd()` laravel in-built output mechanism**.

Comment: `Log::info()` or `Log::debug()` don't write to the browser console, they write to _storage/logs/laravel-YYYY-MM-DD.log_. Also, you have to import `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log`. You can then display them on the fly for ex with `tail -f storage/logs/laravel-2022-01-19.log`.

Answer (score 29):

**It's very simple.**

You can call it from anywhere in APP.

```
$out = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
$out->writeln("Hello from Terminal");
```

Answer (score 14):

Laravel 5.6 simplified this because you now have a `logging.php` config file you could leverage.

The key thing to know is that you want to output to `stdout` and php has a stream wrapper built-in called `php://stdout`. Given that, you could add channel for that wrapper. You would add the stdout "channel" to your channels that you will be logging to.

Here's how the config will basically look:

```
<?php    

return [
  'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

  'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single','stdout'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'stdout' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stdout',
        ],
    ],
];
```

I have more information here - [Laravel 5.6 - Write to the Console](https://medium.com/@2upmedia/laravel-5-6-write-to-the-console-1d55c8e7a43)

Comment: Wow, this was awesome. Just what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: This is great! How would you show the messages in different colours, like the way Commands work when printing $this->info, $this->warning, $this->error etc? I'd like to use Log::info from a service class, so I don't have $this->info available there.

Comment: @thirtyish You could probably use the `tap` option and this package to set the formatter https://github.com/bramus/monolog-colored-line-formatter/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: @2upmedia - So that you're aware: the primary media containing in the information that you linked in "Laravel 5.6 - Write to the Console", is not loading/working/available. That media piece is basically the meat and potatoes of your article, because the line above says: "So this is how it looks like:" with a blank image. Hopefully you can fix that broken link because it looks like a great article that a lot of people can benefit from!

Comment: @MEE thanks. I haven't touched that article for years so I'll see what's going on.

Comment: @MEE fixed it. Thanks for alerting me.

Comment: @2upmedia - no worries, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 2):

You've to config where laravel to store the logs. Default `Log::info()` put the log in the log file not the console. you can use `tail -f logpath` to see the log.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `info()` method

```php
   $this->info("Your Message");
```

[image]

Comment: works only inside a console command, not any class